# Nativescript + Vuejs - Show dialog while app is in background

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am developing an app very similar to Uber in Nativescript + Vuejs.

There is a moment in the flow of the application, where a driver, having accepted a trip, runs the device's default satnav application (eg Google Map, Waze, etc.) to perform GPS navigation. The point is that while the driver is navigating -with the maps application in the foreground- there is a use case where he can receive  an offer to take another trip (as the current trip is soon to end), which he has to confirm or reject/dismiss. Is there a way to do one of the following scenarios:

- Show a dialog that appears above the map application showing trip details and two CTA buttons? Like a dark overlay maybe?
- Return my application to foreground to show the dialog (leaving the maps application in the background). Important detail is that the map application is opened programmatically by my application.

Please remember that I am using nativescript and not Java/Obj-C.

Thank you!

Comment: Out of the box there is no such thing, but NativeScript allows you to reach into native territories and make this happen. If you found any solutions for Java/Obj-C you can translate those into NativeScript/JS calls.

Comment: You will have to run a background service and trigger a notification or dialog from the service.